# Is it possible to add fixed effects in an OLS (multiple) regression on cross section data?

Tags: multiple-regression, binary-data, fixed-effects-model, cross-section

I'm writing my thesis on private equity funds' financial performance and ESG integration. The data is gathered from funds at a single point in time and is therefore cross-sectional data.

I want to run an OLS regression on the below dataset. I was a bit in doubt if I should use a logit model, however, as I understand it, a logit model is only applicable if the dependent variable is binary, which mine is not. I have therefore chosen to use a linear multiple regression model. I am running the models in STATA.

My dataset includes 2,300 funds. My variables are:

Dependent variable: IRR (financial performance) as a continuous variable.

Independent variable: Nominal categorical variable (1: Traditional funds, 2: ESG funds, 3: high ESG funds)

Control variables:

1. Maturity in years: Integer
2. Fund size: Integer
3. Industry: 6 binary variables
4. Geography: 7 binary variables
5. Strategy: 6 binary variables

Is it possible to run a fixed effects model (maturity, fund size, and industry fixed effects) on this model? Or is this not possible on cross-sectional data? I have a difficult time figuring if its possible and have really looked through everything. I hope someone call help!